# Migration multibyte images file name issue

Tags: files, migrations

I have a Drupal website that I transferred it from host A to host B. I have some images uploaded with its Arabic file name, it works fine on host A, but after zipping Drupal files into a zip archieve, sending it to host B, extracting it there and finally run my website there, I found that the file names have been corrupted. the following screen shot demonstrates the issue:

[image]

What's the cause of this issue? How could I keep correct multiple byte file names correctly during zipping and unzipping?

By the way, the two hosts are Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, simply, to compress the folder or files as **tar** not zip. **Tar** does not encode file names so it keeps it as it is in the filesystem. This is the [**Reference**](https://superuser.com/questions/60379/how-can-i-create-a-zip-tgz-in-linux-such-that-windows-has-proper-filenames)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are the two hosts the same host? If not, its highly likely host B does not support arabic writting.

Transfer 1 arabic file, without ziping it, to prove my theory.

Comment: On host B, from Drupal, I have uploaded an image with Arabic file name, also from cPanel I have uploaded another one with Arabic file name too and it works fine. I think that your theory is not correct.